# FPDI : Call to undefined method FPDI::_getrawstream() on Drupal

Tags: drupal, fpdi

I try to use the FPDI lib with Drupal to concatenate pdf together.
I created a class to add a new pdf to fpdi :

```
class PdfGenerator
{
public function importPDF(&$fpdi, $file)
  {
      $pageCount = $fpdi->setSourceFile($file);
      for ($p = 1; $p <= $pageCount; $p++) {
          $tplidx = $fpdi->importPage($p);
          $size = $fpdi->getTemplatesize($tplidx);

          if ($size['w'] > $size['h']) {
              $format = 'L';
          } else {
              $format = 'P';
          }

          $fpdi->addPage($format, array($size['w'], $size['h']));
          $fpdi->useTemplate($tplidx);
      }
  }
}
```

and I call the importPDF method like this:

```
$pdf = new FPDI();
$pdf_path = 'path/to/pdf.pdf';
$pdfGenerator->importPDF($pdf,$pdf_path);
$pdf->Output('test.pdf','I');
```

But unfortunately I have this error :

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method FPDI::_getrawstream() in [..]sites/all/libraries/fpdi/fpdi.php on line 473
```

Do you know the reason for this error ?

thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:
I actually use HTML2PDF before FPDI to generate a PDF.

- HTML2PDF makes an include of an outdated version of TCPDF (5.0.002)

So when I use FPDI, the type of the fpdi object instantiate is TCPDF and not FPDF. And FPDI called a function of TCPDF which appears on the v6 of TCPDF.

**The solution** :
I Downgraded FPDI to the version 1.3.3 to match to html2pdf (v5.0.002)
And I took fpdf_tpl version 1.2.2 to match to the fpdi lib v1.3.3

And this works !

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you update [FPDI](http://www.fpdi.de) and [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org) to their latest versions.

Comment: I use FPDI v1.5.2 and FPDF v1.7. I try the same code on a clean installation without Drupal and it works. I still don't have any solution with Drupal.

Comment: In your Drupal setup an outdated version of TCPDF seems to be loaded before FPDI is loaded.

Comment: Actually, I use html2pdf to generate a dynamic pdf before. In html2pdf the verson of TCPDF is 5.0.002.